# extract a word from a line containing tab and space in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a line having this format:

```
<tab> * li ID
```

I need to obtain the ID value.
I have tried without success:

```
set line="<tab> * li ID"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=^T " %%a in ("!line!") do (
   echo "a=%%a . b=%%b . c=%%c."
)
```

or:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=<tab><space>" %%a in ("!line!") do ( etc)
```

In other words I need to extract the last word from my line.
Is there other method than the ones I have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "line=   * li ID"
FOR %%a in (%line%) do SET result=%%a
ECHO %result%
GOTO :EOF
```

assuming that by `<tab>` you mean <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: That's clever Magoo - leveraging the right tool for the right job. :)